# Java xml writer overrides

Tags: java, xml, dom

My XML (DOM) writer doesn't work as expected. It works just fine adding songs into it using the `addSong()` method, which passes 3 strings into `saveSong()` method.

The `saveSong()` saves them to an `XML`, but when I save it to the `XML` file, it writes what it's supposed to do, but overrides everything else, which it isn' t supposed to do..

I just need it to be like an "list" which you can keep adding songs to, please help!

**Song class:**

```
public class Song {
List<String[]> songs = new ArrayList<String[]>();

public void addSong(String s, String a, String yt){
    String[] songarray= new String[3];
    songarray[0] = s;
    songarray[1] = a;
    songarray[2] = yt;
    songs.add(songarray);
    saveSong(songarray);



}
public void editSong(int i, String s, String a, String yt){
    String[] editsongarray = new String[3];
    editsongarray[0] = s;
    editsongarray[1] = a;
    editsongarray[2] = yt;
    songs.remove(i);
    songs.add(i,editsongarray);
}
public void removeSong(int i){
    songs.remove(i);
}

public String[] getList(int i){
    String[] j = songs.get(i);
    return j;
}
public void saveSong(String[] songl){
    try{

        DocumentBuilderFactory song = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder songBuilder = song.newDocumentBuilder();

            Document doc = songBuilder.newDocument();
            Element playlist = doc.createElement("playlist");
            doc.appendChild(playlist);

            Element songs = doc.createElement("songs");
            playlist.appendChild(songs);

            Attr attr = doc.createAttribute("index");
            attr.setValue("1");
            playlist.setAttributeNode(attr);


            Element name = doc.createElement("name");
            name.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(songl[0]));
            songs.appendChild(name);

            Element artistname = doc.createElement("artistname");
            artistname.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(songl[1]));
            songs.appendChild(artistname);

            Element youtubeurl = doc.createElement("youtubeurl");
            youtubeurl.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(songl[2]));
            songs.appendChild(youtubeurl);

            TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer tr = tf.newTransformer();
            DOMSource dom = new DOMSource(doc);
            StreamResult sr = new StreamResult(new File("c:\\Applications\\staff.xml"));

            tr.transform(dom, sr);

            System.out.println("done");

        }catch(ParserConfigurationException pce){
            pce.printStackTrace();
        }catch(TransformerException fce){
            fce.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Main class:**
*Passes string to `addSong()`, which passes them to `saveSong()`, which writes them in a `XML` file.*

```
public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Song Song = new Song();
        Song.addSong("This is", "A very good","Song");
    }
}
```

Comment: Well what *was* it meant to do to the existing file? If you wanted to modify an existing file (e.g. adding elements) then you should parse the existing file, add any relevant elements, and then save it again.#

Comment: @JonSkeet Ya, i was supposed to add content to the existing file :-)..  I need it to store song details, and load them again to a musicplayer i made.. you know any good tutorials for parse - add - save?? sounds a litte complicated to me.. Thanks for your help! - /Oliver

Comment: Rather than look for a single tutorial, why don't you research each topic? There must be tens of thousands of pages showing you how you can parse an XML file in Java, for example.

Comment: There are a bunch of good XML-in-Java tutorials on IBM's [DeveloperWorks XML](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/) website, among other places.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't test this code, Please modify accordingly.

```
    try{
    // open your existing xml file first
       FileInputStream in=new FileInputStream("c:\\Applications\\staff.xml");           

         DocumentBuilderFactory song = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder songBuilder = song.newDocumentBuilder();
          // Parse this file as input document
        Document docIn=builderel.parse(staff.xml);  
        //Define your root Element here, I am assuming it as <root>
        Element root;
        // now we will add all elements in your root
        Element playlist = root.createElement("playlist");
        // Now add all new childs in root.Here i am adding only one. Add rest of the child as per your need in root
          root.appendChild(playlist);
        //Now add this new root in your output doc
          docIn.appendChild(root);
        TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer tr = tf.newTransformer();
        DOMSource dom = new DOMSource(docIn);
        StreamResult sr = new StreamResult(new File("c:\\Applications\\staff.xml"));

        tr.transform(dom, sr);

        System.out.println("done");
```

You need to define an empty staff.xml first, having only root node in it,

```
c:\\Applications\\staff.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
              <root></root>
```

I hope , you will get the idea now.
To summarize,

We are opening above staff.xml

Adding all elements in existing root node.

Override existing file having new elemnts along with existing one.

Your output will be,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
              <root>
               <playist></playlist>
               <playist></playlist>
               <playist></playlist>
                ....
              </root>
```

And when next time you will open your staff.xml and parse it as docIn your existing playlist node wont get override as you are adding in existing root node. get it?